# String Occurrence According to the order

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a Problem where i need to find the first occurrence of the char according to the order which they occur in the given String.

For Example :

I have a String **"Unitedin"** where the char **"n"** and **"i"** have a multiple occurrence in the String.
**char n** occurred at charAt(1,7)
**char i** occurred at charAt (2,6)
But the char **"i"** had occurred first before char **"n"**.

I have Tried Something like this But i am not getting the required output.Can Anyone Help me please?
Note : **Challenge is Not to use any type of List or Hashset or Hashmap**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            StringBuilder nodup = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder dup = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
            String instring = in.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < instring.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < instring.length(); j++) {
                    if (instring.charAt(i) == instring.charAt(j)) {
                        nodup.append(instring.charAt(i));

                    } else {
                        dup.append(instring.charAt(i));
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.print(nodup.toString());
```

i am getting the OutPut as : **ni** . but the Required output is **in**.

Comment: The first "n" in "Unitedin" occurs before the first "i" in "Unitedin", so if I understand you correctly, "ni" is correct.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by _the first occurrence of the char according to the order_ - which char, which order?

Comment: @Neil If you Scan the Char in the given String, The Occurrence of the `i` is First then followed by `n` . hope i clarified .

Comment: @Armali In the Given String we have Set of Char `u``n``i``t`e``d``i`n`. are the chars in the string. here as you can see the order of the first occurrence `i` is first followed by `n`. hope it helps.

Comment: @dev2kun I think I understand what you mean.  I submitted an answer.  Please let me know.

Comment: You write: _But the char **"i"** had occurred first before char **"n"**._ That's false; in **"Unitedin"**, **"n"** comes first (2nd place), thereafter **"i"** (3rd place).

Comment: @Armali Its not Exactly like that!. Just Scan the Char of the given String. `i` occurred first. like the difference between the occurrence is less right. something like that. i.e, **the char position of `i` is = charAt(2) and charAt(6) . so the difference is 4. likewise for `n` the difference is 6** hence `i` first.

Comment: You write: _`i` occurred first._ That's false; in `Unitedin`, `n` comes first.

Comment: @Armali you can think something like this... Just Start Searching from the middle of the string and go both ways!

Comment: If there are special directions for searching, you'd have to state that in the question post itself. Also, one cannot _go both ways_ at the same time while expecting a deterministic result.

Answer (score 0):

The [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class works really well for your particular problem.  You may iterate the character array from your input string, and then add the characters, along with their counts, as keys, into the `LinkedHashMap`.  Since `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order, to get the output you want you need only iterate the map and print out all keys whose counts are greater than one.  The order of the character keys will be fixed at the first occurrence of each letter.

```
String input = "Unitedin";
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (char chr : input.toCharArray()) {
    Integer count = map.get(chr);
    map.put(chr, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
}
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > 1) System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
```

This prints:

```
n
i
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Tim Biegeleisen but we are not suppose to use any type of **List** or **Hashset** or **Hashmap** .sorry i forgot to mention in question

Comment: Bummer, I had a good idea here.  I will leave this up, unless I get some downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to view the *first recurrence* of a character, then this should do it.  The order will be the order in which a *repeated* character is found in your string.

```
String input = "Unitedin";
Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (char chr : input.toCharArray()) {
    Integer count = map.get(chr);
    count = count != null ? count + 1 else 1;
    map.put(chr, count);

    if(count > 1) {
        sb.append(chr);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());  // Output:  in
```

EDIT:  I understand from your comment that you cannot use an instance of List, HashSet, or HashMap?  Then is LinkedHashMap allowed?  If not, then you'll need to recreate that functionality somehow.

You could map characters a-z and A-Z in an int array of 52 (26 + 26).  Rather than insert the count into a map, you map the character to its appropriate spot in the array and update the count.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But Challenge is Not to use any type of List or Hashset or Hashmap. @Neil

Comment: Any Logic in mind to solve? its all over my head. it will be Really helpfully!

Comment: @dev2kun I updated my answer.  Hopefully this will point you in the right direction!

Comment: Sorry we cannot use that too!. But i have a logic not sure how to implement. Can you help me? i will walk through it @Neil

Comment: We can use `int m = input.indexOf('instring.charAt(i) ', startingindex) - i` which will return a value.  we need to store both value `m` and `i` not sure how to do it. Then value m which ever is less. print char(i). hope you get it. But need help how to implement @Neil

Comment: @dev2kun If you do it this way, it is O(n^2) time.  My way requires only one pass.  However if you wish to do it this way, you must, for each char in your string, check if another char exists further on, and in that case, add to a StringBuilder.

Comment: How to implement in code? Not sure how to do! Can you show me in code?